# Approach for useEffect to avoid exhaustive-dep warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I keep running into situations where the `exhaustive-dep` rule complains. In a simple below I want to reset the value whenever the props.id value changes:

```
const TestComponent = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(props.value);
  }, [props.id]);

  const saveValue = () => {
    props.save(value);
  }

  return <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} onBlur={saveValue} />;
};
```

However, the lint rule wants me to also add `props.value` to the dependencies. If I do that it will effectively break the component since the effect will run on every change to the input and thus reset the state.

Is there a "right" way of achieving this behavior?

Comment: To tell you the "right" way, i'll need to know why are you trying to copy props into state. That's very rarely the right thing to do. What does state give you that the props do not? Is the value prop supposed to be an initial value, but then you also want another prop that can tell TestComponent to reset itself?

Comment: @NicholasTower the more complete version of this basically tracks the local state then saves it onBlur, i can update the example with more detail.

Comment: And the `id` prop, is its sole purpose to reset TestComponent?

Comment: @NicholasTower Correct, while the user is typing we want to ignore a new value prop (from an api response for instance) because what the user is typing will ultimately override that anyway. If the `id` prop changes we want to force change it since the underlying entity being edited has changed (possibly caused by some navigation event and the component is being reused with a new id/value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're written your component is in a half controlled half uncontrolled style, which is difficult to do. I would recommend going either fully controlled, or fully uncontrolled.

A "controlled" component is one where it just acts on the props its given. It takes the value from its props and forwards it to the input, with no state. When the input changes, it calls an onChange prop. When the input blurs, it calls an onBlur prop. All the business logic is handled by the parent component.

The other option is an uncontrolled component, which is mostly what you have. The parent will pass in a prop for the initial value. I'd recommend naming it initialValue so it's clear this will only be checked once. After that, everything is managed by the child component. This means your useEffect goes away entirely:

```
const TestComponent = props = {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.initialValue);

  const saveValue = () => {
    props.save(value);
  }

  return <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} onBlur={saveValue} />;
}
```

So how do you reset this then? With a `key`. The parent component can use a standard react key to tell react that it should unmount the old component and mount a new one:

```
const ParentComponent = props = {
  // some code...
  return <TestComponent key={id} initialValue={"whatever"} />
}
```

As long as the id doesn't change, the TestComponent will do its thing, starting with the initialValue passed in. When the id changes, the TestComponent unmounts and a new one mounts in its place, which will start with the initialValue it's given.